# Opening image from http in python 3

Tags: python, http, image-processing

I know there are a thousand questions like that out there but none of the provided solutions do actually work.
I am using pythong 3.4.
I would like to directly open the url as an image, not store it first on the disk.

Basically the code comes down to this

```
from PIL import Image <br />
import urllib.request <br />
... <br />
opener = urllib.request.build_opener() <br />
file = opener.open("http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel") <br />
img = Image.open(file.read()) <br />
width, height = img.size
```

This yields for me an error. I also tried it without the  
    .read()  
 and with 
    file = urllib.request.urlopen("...")
both with and without the .read()

Basically I am lost. The only thing I can do is change the error that python is throwing at me. Thanks for any help! 
Error messages with the above mentioned version: 
TypeError: embedded NUL character 
Without the read() 
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek 
With "urllib.request.urlopen("...") without .read() 
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek 
with .read() 
TypeError: embedded NUL character

Comment: First of all, format your code correctly, What is the error that python throws at you?

Comment: added errors in the question

Answer (score 4):

To avoid using tkinter and to avoid writing the file locally, use a buffer:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib
from io import BytesIO

f = urllib.urlopen("http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel")
b = BytesIO(f.read())
i = Image.open(b)

i # <PIL.TgaImagePlugin.TgaImageFile image mode=P size=512x17410 at 0x7FBA4A3712D8>
```

This is using 2.7, which doesn't have `urllib.request`, so modify this as required.

Also, be aware that this image appears to be malformed/invalid

Comment: @notsoimportant The best way to say this is to mark the answer as correct!